# stuck on get the answers for each question, quiz

Tags: javascript, arrays, web-applications

Please help me with this exercise! 
I got an API link https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10  and I have to get the data from that API to make a simple quiz with javascript (yes SIMPLE but I can’t figure out how to do it, difficult for me). The problem is I did get the questions appear on the page but 10 questions have the same answers. I mean it should be 10 questions with 10 different arrays with different answers inside. I'm stuck here and don't know how to do it.:(

$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    var myQuestions = data.results;

```
for (question of myQuestions) {
    var correctAnswer = question.correct_answer;
    var totAnswers = question.incorrect_answers;
    totAnswers.push(correctAnswer);
    // console.log(totAnswers);
}

function buildQuiz() {
    const output = [];

    myQuestions.forEach((currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {
        const answers = [];
        for (value of totAnswers) {
            console.log(value);
            answers.push(
              `<label>
                <input type="radio" name="question${questionNumber}" value="${value}">
                ${value} 
              </label>`
            );
          }
        output.push(
            `<div class="slide">
                   <div class="question"> ${currentQuestion.question} </div>
                   <div class="answers"> ${answers.join("")} </div>
                 </div>`
        );
    });
    quizContainer.innerHTML = output.join('');
}
```

Here is how it looks like now:

[image]

I think that the problem is where I use the loop for the totAnswers variable. But I don’t understand why. 
Can anyone give me some tips please?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please, debug your code first.

Comment: Hi! thanks for comment! But the problem is I don't know where to bedug. I'm such a newbier! :(

Comment: Start reading [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand why are you forming `totAnswers`
What you want to achieve can be done like this:

```
function buildQuiz() {
    const output = myQuestions.map((currentQuestion, questionNumber) => (
    `<div class="slide">
        <div class="question">
             ${currentQuestion.question} 
        </div>
        <div class="answers">
${currentQuestion.incorrect_answers.concat(currentQuestion.correct_answer).join('')} 
        </div>
    </div>`))
    quizContainer.innerHTML = output.join('');
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your tip! I have try this method before, but I can't put in the input form for each answers with it. I'm using totAnswers just because I think it may become easier to handle the array :D Actually I don't know what I'm doing, being crazy because of coding :))